# ColorFilter doesn't work for TextView background

Tags: android, background, textview, background-color, colorfilter

I want to change color of several TextView elements background using ColorFilters. I've tried several ways to do it. Two of them are bellow:

```
TextView tvLeftTop, tvLeftBottom;

tvLeftTop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_LeftTop);
tvLeftBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_LeftBottom);

float[] cmData = new float[]{
                        1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                        0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(cmData);
ColorFilter filter1 = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
ColorFilter filter2 = new PorterDuffColorFilter(0x20003300, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);

tvLeftBottom.getBackground().setColorFilter(filter1);
tvLeftTop.getBackground().setColorFilter(filter2);
```

Both TextView are contained in GridLayout. Here is the appropriate part of .xml activity file:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_LeftTop"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="#6A77B7"

            android:text="Title1" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_LeftBottom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:background="#D64F97"

            android:text="Title2" />
</GridLayout>
```

But there is no effect for both target text views (their colors are not changed). 
What I am doing wrong?

P.S. Colors' values are test, so there are entire strings (not values from .xml file). I think it doesn't matter now.

Comment: There is additional information. I try to change TextView color using SeekBar. And now I noticed interesting thing. I added `tvLeftTop.setText(""+i);` after `tvLeftTop.getBackground().setColorFilter(filter2);` and color changed (`i` is the value of the seek bar position). It seems that refresh of TextView is requred. But I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
tvLeftBottom.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
```

Your textview don't have background so you can't set the color. 
Set your color as the background.

Comment: TextView's background colors are specified in .xml file in android:background. But still I tried your advice.Unfortunately, it doesn't work.